# Which AWK program can do this manipulation?

Tags: awk

Given a file containing a structure arranged like the following (with fields separated by SP or HT)

```
4 5 6 2 9 8 4 8
m d 6 7 9 5 4 g
t 7 4 2 4 2 5 3
h 5 6 2 5 s 3 4
r 5 7 1 2 2 4 1
4 1 9 0 5 6 d f
x c a 2 3 4 5 9
0 0 3 2 1 4 q w
```

Which AWK program do I need to get the following output?

```
  4 5
  m d
  t 7
  h 5
  r 5
  4 1
  x c
  0 0
  6 2
  6 7
  4 2
  6 2
  7 1
  9 0
  a 2
  3 2
  9 8
  9 5
  4 2
  5 s
  2 2
  5 6
  3 4
  1 4
  4 8
  4 g
  5 3
  3 4
  4 1
  d f
  5 9
  q w
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Postscript

Please bear in mind,

1. My input file is much larger than the one depicted in this question.
2. My computer science skills are seriously limited.
3. This task has been imposed on me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO its highly encouraged for Original poster of question to do add their efforts(irrespective or right or wrong) in their question, so kindly do add the same in your question, thank you.

Comment: What is the field delimiter - TAB or blank? How many columns: 8 or substantially more?

Comment: Is the number of columns known in advance?

Comment: @TimurShtatland sometimes the field delimiters are all TAB (HT) and in some other files the field delimiters are all BLANK (SP) and there are over 1 million columns but the rows are always 8. Also I would also l like be able select the output in groups of 4 or 8 or 16 or 32 or 64 etc, not necessarily the group of 2 in the example.

Comment: @Cyrus the number of columns is always known in advance and is always over a million.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my first encounter with AWK was yesterday and I just downloaded "Effective awk Programming: Universal Text Processing and Pattern Matching by Arnold Robbins" a few hours ago...I am a Heat and Mass Transfer laboratory instructor in a school...I really need this solution and of course I will be making attempts as I grapple with my new book

Comment: @two_big_a_pac I assume you _acquired_ that particular book? ;-)

Comment: @kvantour yes I did acquire that book.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
awk -v n=4 '
    function join(start, end,    result, i) {
        for (i=start; i<=end; i++)
            result = result $i (i==end ? ORS : FS)
        return result
    }
    {
        c=0
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=n) {
            c++
            col[c] = col[c] join(i, i+n-1)
        }
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=c; i++)
            printf "%s", col[i]  # the value already ends with newline
    }
' file
```

The [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) has a short primer on awk, so read that too.

---

#### Benchmarking

1. create an input file with 1,000,000 columns and 8 rows (as specified by OP)

   ```perl
   #!perl
   my $cols = 2**20; # 1,048,576
   my $rows = 8;
   my @alphabet=( 'a'..'z', 0..9 );
   my $size = scalar @alphabet;

   for ($r=1; $r <= $rows; $r++) {
       for ($c = 1; $c <= $cols; $c++) {
           my $idx = int rand $size;
           printf "%s ", $alphabet[$idx];
       }
       printf "\n";
   }
   ```

   ```sh
   $ perl createfile.pl > input.file
   $ wc input.file
          8  8388608 16777224 input.file
   ```
2. time various implementations: I use the [fish](/questions/tagged/fish) shell, so the timing output is different from bash's

   - my awk

     ```
     $ time awk -f columnize.awk -v n=4 input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in    3.62 secs   fish           external
        usr time    3.49 secs    0.24 millis    3.49 secs
        sys time    0.11 secs    1.96 millis    0.11 secs

     $ wc output.file
      2097152  8388608 16777216 output.file
     ```
   - Timur's perl:

     ```
     $ time perl -lan columnize.pl input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in    3.25 secs   fish           external
        usr time    2.97 secs    0.16 millis    2.97 secs
        sys time    0.27 secs    2.87 millis    0.27 secs
     ```
   - Ravinder's awk

     ```
     $ time awk -f columnize.ravinder input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in    4.01 secs   fish           external
        usr time    3.84 secs    0.18 millis    3.84 secs
        sys time    0.15 secs    3.75 millis    0.14 secs
     ```
   - kvantour's awk, first version

     ```
     $ time awk -f columnize.kvantour -v n=4 input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in    3.84 secs   fish           external
        usr time    3.71 secs  166.00 micros    3.71 secs
        sys time    0.11 secs  1326.00 micros    0.11 secs
     ```
   - kvantour's second awk version: Crtl-C interrupted after a few minutes

     ```
     $ time awk -f columnize.kvantour2 -v n=4 input.file > output.file
     ^C
     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in  260.80 secs   fish           external
        usr time  257.39 secs    0.13 millis  257.39 secs
        sys time    1.68 secs    2.72 millis    1.67 secs

     $ wc output.file
      9728 38912 77824 output.file
     ```

     The `$0=a[j]` line is pretty expensive, as it has to parse the string into fields each time.
   - dawg's python

     ```
     $ timeout 60s fish -c 'time python3 columnize.py input.file 4 > output.file'
     [... 60 seconds later ...]
     $ wc output.file
      2049  8196 16392 output.file
     ```
3. another interesting data point: using different awk implementations. I'm on a Mac with GNU awk and mawk installed via homebrew

   - with many columns, few rows

     ```
     $ time gawk -f columnize.awk -v n=4 input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in    3.78 secs   fish           external
        usr time    3.62 secs  174.00 micros    3.62 secs
        sys time    0.13 secs  1259.00 micros    0.13 secs
     ```

     ```
     $ time /usr/bin/awk -f columnize.awk -v n=4 input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in   17.73 secs   fish           external
        usr time   14.95 secs    0.20 millis   14.95 secs
        sys time    2.72 secs    3.45 millis    2.71 secs
     ```

     ```
     $ time mawk -f columnize.awk -v n=4 input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in    2.01 secs   fish           external
        usr time  1892.31 millis    0.11 millis  1892.21 millis
        sys time   95.14 millis    2.17 millis   92.97 millis
     ```
   - with many rows, few columns, this test took **over half an hour** on a MacBook Pro, 6 core Intel cpu, 16GB ram

     ```
     $ time mawk -f columnize.awk -v n=4 input.file > output.file

     ________________________________________________________
     Executed in   32.30 mins   fish           external
        usr time   23.58 mins    0.15 millis   23.58 mins
        sys time    8.63 mins    2.52 millis    8.63 mins
     ```

Comment: Curious: Please retry you benchmark with millions of rows and 8 columns?

Comment: You're welcome to do it, but it's not the OP's scenario.

Comment: The issue is the shape of the date. Millions of **rows** x 8 vs millions of **columns** x 8. If you have millions of **rows** these awks (except for kvantour's second one) are super slow. If you millions of **columns** the python that wrote is super slow.

Comment: @dawg, I did try a few runs with the input file transposed (few columns many rows) and I can confirm your observations: python is speedy, my awk is slow

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl script:

```
perl -lane '
push @rows, [@F];
END {
    my $delim = "\t";
    my $cols_per_group = 2;
    my $col_start = 0;
    while ( 1 ) {
         for my $row ( @rows ) {
             print join $delim, @{$row}[ $col_start .. ($col_start + $cols_per_group - 1) ];
         }
         $col_start += $cols_per_group;
         last if ($col_start + $cols_per_group - 1) > $#F;
    } 
}
' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**This script reads the file into memory.** This is okay for most modern computers and the file sizes in question.

Each line is split on whitespace (use `-F'\t'` for `TAB` as delimiter) into array `@F`. The references to this array for each line are stored as elements in array `@rows`. After the file is read, and the end of the script (in the `END { ... }` block), the contents of the file are printed in groups of columns, with `$cols_per_group` columns per group. Columns are delimited by `$delim`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: @two_big_a_pac Updated the answer based on your comments.

Comment: This is fast even on larger files. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with ONLY shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){
    arr[i]=(arr[i]?arr[i] ORS :"")$i OFS $(i+1)
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){
    print arr[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: Beware: This becomes **super slow** on larger files. Try making the example `12M` and try this script.

Comment: @dawg, Thanks for warning here, I haven't tested it with huge files, that's why i had written checked with shown samples only, will try to add another solution if I could later, thank you.

Comment: Reareading the comments, my warning may be premature. The `awk` becomes super slow with data with millions of ROWS but he says he has millions of COLUMNS and aways 8 rows. Different analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Since we all love awk, here is another one:

```
awk -v n=2 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { j=int((i-1)/n); a[j] = a[j] $i (i%n==0 || i==NF ?ORS:OFS) }}
            END{for(j=0;j<=int(NF/n);j++) printf "%s", a[j]}'
```

This will output exactly what is requested by the OP.

**How does it work?**

Awk performs actions per record/line it reads. For each record, it processes all the fields and appends them to a set of strings stored in an array `a`. It processes it in such way that `a[1]` contains the first `n` columns. `a[2]` the second set of `n` columns, etc. The relation between field number and string number is based on the equation `int((i-1)/n)`.

When creating the strings, we try to keep track if we need to add a field separator `OFS` or a new line (record separator `ORS`). We decide this based on the modulus of the field number and the total number of columns we expect (i.e. `n`). Note, that we always use ORS if we process the last field.

**An alternative approach:**
Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598986/which-awk-program-can-do-this-manipulation/65600239?noredirect=1#comment116008105_65600239) [Dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg), a flaw in the above code was found. He informed us that the program scales really badly when moving to large files. The real reason for this is not 100% known, but I assume it is from constantly having to rewrite memory by doing operations as `a[j] = a[j] $i (i%n==0 || i==NF ?ORS:OFS)`. This can be eliminated by just buffering the entire file and do all operations in the end:

```
awk -v n=2 '{a[NR]=$0}
            END{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=n)
                   for(j=1;j<=NR;++j) {
                      $0=a[j]
                      for(k=0;k<n&&(i+k<=NF);++k)
                         printf "%s%s", $(i+k), ((i+k==NF || ((i+k) % n == 0)) ? ORS : OFS) 
                   }
            }' file
```

Note: the latter seems only efficient for a small amount of columns. This is because of the constant re-splitting done with `$0=a[j]`. The split takes much more time due to the large amount of fields. The complexity of this system is O(NF^2*NR)

**A final alternative approach:** While the first solution is fast for large amount of columns and small amount of rows, the second is fast for small amount of columns and large amount of rows. Below you find a final version that is not as fast, but stable and produces the same timing for the transposed files.

```
awk -v n=2 '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=n) {
                s=""
                for(k=0;k<n&&(i+k<=NF);++k) 
                   s=s  $(i+k)  ((i+k==NF || ((i+k) % n == 0)) ? "ORS" : OFS);
                a[i,NR]=s 
             }
            }
            END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=n)for(j=1;j<=NR;++j) printf "%s",a[i,j]}' file
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is precisely the form of the output I was looking for.  I have tested it in bash with the same example and  I hope to test it again at the office with a real dataset first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: @two_big_a_pac Glad to hear it.  If any of these answers helped you out, feel free to accept it. I would take the answer which is most understandable for you.

Comment: Beware: This becomes **super slow** on larger files. Try making the example `12M` and try this script.

Comment: @dawg this is very impressive! From a given filesize, the program just becomes extremly slow. Probably has something to do with the total CPU cache available.

Comment: The slowdown is strictly based on the shape of the data. If it is 8 columns by millions of rows, it slows down exponentially using the `awk` all in memory approach; if it is 8 rows by millions of columns, the opposite is true!

Comment: @dawg It's a close call on the 12MB one, but your python is faster: (python: 4.72s, awk: 5.15s)

Comment: Your second one is **significantly** faster! Great job!!

Comment: @dawg the following are results for a 22.6MB, which for our purposes are indeed excellent, considering that this task was daunting just 48 hours ago:

time awk -v n=8 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { j=int((i-1)/n); a[j] = a[j] $i (i%n==0 || i==NF ?ORS:OFS) }}
>             END{for(j=0;j<=int(NF/n);j++) printf "%s", a[j]}' input_file  >  output_file


real 0m13.972s
user 0m12.202s
sys 0m0.629s

Answer (score 2):

My old answer is below and no longer applicable...

You can use this awk for a file that could be millions of rows or millions of columns. The basic scheme is to suck all the values into a single array then use indexing arithmetic and nested loops at the end to get the correct order:

```
$ cat col.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        vals[++numVals] = $i
        }
    }
    END {
    for(col_offset=0; col_offset + cols <= NF; col_offset+=cols) {
        for (i=1; i<=numVals; i+=NF) {
            for(j=0; j<cols; j++) {
                printf "%s%s", vals[i+j+col_offset], (j<cols-1 ? FS : ORS)
                }
        } 
    }
}

$ awk -f col.awk -v cols=2 file
4 5
m d
t 7
h 5
...
3 4
4 1
d f
5 9
q w
```

My old answer is based on the dramatic slowdown seen in most of these awks with a large number of rows.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653860/awk-super-slow-processing-many-rows-but-not-many-columns?noredirect=1#65654672) for more discussion regarding the slowdown.

The comments in the original answer below are no longer applicable.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Only here for consistency...

The `awk` solutions here are all good **for small files**. What they all have in common is the file either needs to fit in RAM or the OS virtual memory is an acceptable fall back if the file does not fit in RAM. But with a larger file, since the time of the `awk` increases exponentially, you can have **a very bad result.** With a `12MB` version of your file, an in-memory awk becomes unusably slow.

This is the case if there are millions of **rows** not millions of **columns**.

The only alternative to an in-memory solution is reading the file multiple times or managing temp files yourself. (Or use a scripting language that manages VM internally, such as Perl or Python... Timur Shatland's [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65599187/298607) is fast even on huge files.)

`awk` does not have an easy mechanism to loop over a file multiple times until a process is done. You would need to use the shell to do that and invoke `awk` multiple times.

Here is a `python` script that reads a file line-by-line and prints `cols` number of columns until all the original columns have been printed

```
$ cat sys.py
import sys
filename=sys.argv[1]
cols=int(sys.argv[2])
offset=0
delimiter=" "

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    max_cols=len(f.readline().split())

while offset<max_cols:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:  
        for line in f:
            col_li=line.rstrip().split()
            l=len(col_li)
            max_cols=l if max_cols>l else l
            print(delimiter.join(col_li[offset:offset+cols]))

        offset+=cols
```

It is counterintuitive, but it is often significantly faster and more efficient to read a file multiple times than it is to gulp the entire thing -- if that gulp then results in a bad result with larger data.

So how does this perform compared to one of the  `awk`s in this post? Let's time it.

Given your example, the in memory `awk` will likely be faster:

```
$ cat file
4 5 6 2 9 8 4 8
m d 6 7 9 5 4 g
t 7 4 2 4 2 5 3
h 5 6 2 5 s 3 4
r 5 7 1 2 2 4 1
4 1 9 0 5 6 d f
x c a 2 3 4 5 9
0 0 3 2 1 4 q w

$ time python pys.py file 2 >file2
real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.016s

$ time awk -v n=2 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { 
  j=int((i-1)/n); a[j] = a[j] $i (i%n==0 || i==NF ?ORS:OFS) }}
  END{for(j=0;j<=int(NF/n);j++) printf "%s", a[j]}' file >file3
real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.003s
```

And that is true. BUT, let's make the file 1000x bigger with this Python script:

```
txt='''\
4 5 6 2 9 8 4 8
m d 6 7 9 5 4 g
t 7 4 2 4 2 5 3
h 5 6 2 5 s 3 4
r 5 7 1 2 2 4 1
4 1 9 0 5 6 d f
x c a 2 3 4 5 9
0 0 3 2 1 4 q w
'''

with open('/tmp/file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt*1000)              # change the 1000 to the multiple desired

# file will have 8000 lines and about 125KB
```

Rerun those timings, same way, and you get:

```
#python
real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.015s

# awk
real    0m0.050s
user    0m0.043s
sys 0m0.004s
```

About the same time... Now make the file BIGGER by multiplying the original by 100,000 to get 800,000 lines and 12MB and run the timing again:

```
# python
real    0m3.475s
user    0m3.434s
sys 0m0.038s

#awk
real    22m45.118s
user    16m40.221s
sys 6m4.652s
```

With a 12MB file, the in memory method becomes essentially unusable since the VM system on this computer with is subject to massive disc swapping to manage that particular type of memory allocation. It is likely `O n**2` or worse. This computer is a 2019 Mac Pro 16 core Xeon with 192GB memory, so it is not hardware...